# Request historical information in Sui API

Tags: sui

In other blockchains, it is possible to call API method and get not the latest info but historical view. For example, I might be interested in address's balance at specific block height vs the current balance. Sometimes this is achieved by providing optional parameter (ETH way), sometimes with request header (Aptos way). I'm wondering if there is something similar in Sui. Documentation did not reveal an easy way of achieving that, maybe there is complicated way? In particular I need a view on address's stakes and unclaimed rewards at specific block height. Latest info is provided by `suix_getStakes`

Answer (score 1):

There are RPC methods to get earlier versions of objects: `sui_tryGetPastObject` but unless the node you are connecting to has indexing as well, objects generations will get 'pruned'.

Sui is moving to a GraphQL RPC where the nodes are required to have indexing so this may be attainable with consistency and confidence once that rolls (appox Q124).

**History via RPC**:

So this is a bit tedious but Staked objects are Sui Objects. As such, each has a 'previous transaction digest (you can see this for example on testnet with `sui client object 0x77851d73e7c1227c048fc7cbf21ff9053faa872950dd33f5d0cb5b40a79d9d99` or via Sui Explorer.

It then goes into a rinse and repeat cycle (pseudo here):

1. Query the object, get the previous transaction digest
2. Query that transaction digest
3. Scan the results (events, changes, etc.) to find your object ID and version/sequence number.
4. With version/sequence, use `sui_tryGetPastObject` and get previous transaction digest
5. Go to step 2

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at `sui_tryGetPastObject`. Can you please elaborate how can I use it to get stakes view from the past (current view is provided by `suix_getStakes`)

Comment: Updated answer, it is not so straight forward...